# Coefficients of Elliptic Curve over Finite Fields

Tags: elliptic-curves

When talking about elliptic curve over finite fields in ECC, we often assume that the elliptic curve can be written in the Weierstrass form

$$y^2=x^3+Ax+B, \quad A,B\in \mathbb{F}_q$$.

where $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a field of characteristic not $2$ and $3$. (For example, Schoof's algorithm to compute $\#E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ assumes this. )

1. In practice, would $A$ and $B$ ever be non-integer coefficients(suppose we are working over $q=p^n$)? That is to say $A=\underbrace{1+...+1}_{\text{sum of }1}$ or might we pick $A,B$ to be other elements from $\mathbb{F}_q$?
2. How would these algorithms that assume the Weierstrass model, generalize to say elliptic curves over fields of characteristic $2$ or $3$? For example, Koblitz curves are a class of elliptic curves of the form $y^2+xy=x^3+ax+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$?

Comment: Note that $A$ and $B$ have to be field elements or they have an equivalent representation as a field element. Therefore there cannot be a non-integer $A$ or $B$ if you're using an integer-based field like $\mathbb F_p$. Of course if you use $\mathbb F_q$ for some $q=p^n$ then you're usually using polynomials anyways but still have some "integer encoding" of them for computer representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $A$ and $B$ can be non-integers if you're working with an extension field. For example, this happens with pairing-friendly curves where you need to work with elliptic curves over e.g. $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$.
2. Depends on the algorithm. For counting elliptic curve points, the "hard" part is computing $\#E(\mathbb{F}_p)$. If you compute that, than it's easy to compute $\#E(\mathbb{F}_{p^k})$; see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144194/how-to-find-the-order-of-elliptic-curve-over-finite-field-extension). In the Koblitz curve case it's even easier since computing $\#E(\mathbb{F}_{2})$ is trivial (it's either 2 or 4 depending on the curve).